# How To put Audio song in NSdata In iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, nsdata

I want to hold ipod Library song in NSData to send on Webservice.
how i can get that song in NSdata

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that unfortunately (at least without doing something 'illegal'). Apple has iPod Library access API: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765

However these only allow you to pick songs, read meta data, tell ipod to play songs... not much else

Comment: I upload iphone library song to server if you want then i can show code to you

Comment: Yeah that would be nice. Does it use only documented methods and work on non-jailbroken devices?

Comment: Hello Nick I upload ipod library song to webserver it is documneted methods and accept by apple use assets library